# If photons lose frequency (due to redshift) can they reach 0 Hz? What would happen then?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, photons, frequency

I haven't got much knowledge about this topic and I would like to know it.

Comment: Due to doppler effect it is impossible because it would require something going with $c$. Due to gravitational redshift I think it is possible, but only for a remote observer, probably a GR guru will soon explain it correctly.

Comment: In addition to other reasons (search for does light lose energy due to redshift, you might be suprised) such photons have such low energy that they in principle could never be measured. Any physical measuring device would have a minimal energy threshold. Science can only answer questions that can be empirically tested, so this question is technically unanswerable.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they can, or rather the photon source can <del>vanish behind</del> be hidden behind an event horizon (cf black holes in case of gravitational redshift, the [cosmic event horizon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_horizon#Cosmic_event_horizon) in case of cosmological redshift due to the metric expansion of space or the [Rindler horizon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rindler_coordinates#The_Rindler_horizon) in case of acceleration; for any finite relative velocity between source and observer, the redshift will of course stay finite, though...).

To clarify, 0 Hz photons do not exist (0 Hz means no energy, ie the electromagnetic field remains undisturbed) and thus obviously cannot be measured, but our theories predict a continuous increase in redshift, and the event horizon is the place where it goes to infinity.

Comment: You cannot observe anything vanishing behind an event horizon.

Comment: @RobJeffries: 'vanish' in the sense of comparing two different situations, not in the sense of observing a process of horizon crossing

Comment: @Christoph thanks for putting up with my pedantic post, I learned a lot from following your comment links.  I appreciate your help.

Comment: @count_to_10, no problem - my post was more of an off-the-cuff remark than a proper answer, and you helpfully pointed out where clarification was necessary

Answer (score 2):

There is little mystery.

In special relativity, as @peterh said, it goes to infinity only for an observer going at speed c with respect to the source. Only massless particles can do that, so you can't be such an observer.

In general relativity you also can't. Two cases that shows it, one near a black hole, and one the event horizon.

The cosmic event horizon is discussed in the answer by Christoph. At the cosmic event horizon the light emitted now cannot reach us. The universe is expanding faster than c, and anything that happens NOW (in comoving time) beyond that we can't see, it can not affect us. From Wikipedia,  that is about 5 Gpc. Our particle horizon is different, and so is the Hubble horizon, see the wiki article 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cosmological_horizons#Event_horizon

Another horizon, an event horizon, can be obtained for the Schwarzschild spherically symmetric (and you can for Kerr also), and it is, and you can see it at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redshift. The redshit for light emitted there would be infinite. In fact the event horizon is where any light emitted near there, inside the black hole, going out, ends up. The horizon is a light like surface. At the Schwarzschild black hole horizon the redshift is infinite, and light cannot escape.

Comment: Amazing. Mind-boggling.